# RegEx in SQL Server 2008

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008, substring

I am not very familiar with RegEx and I have a scenario whereby I think the best option is to use RegEx. Actually, I have a column which hold values starting with a character, followed by numeric, ex. X10, Z49332, x0909.

The regEx should validate;

- That the value start with a letter
- The following characters should be numeric
- No letter should be present after or in between the numerics
- The leading letter can be either Upper/Lower case

I also read that SQL Server 2008 doesn't support RegEx and I am actually on a SQL Server 2008 platform. If so, how do I proceed?

Can anyone help please?

How do I check if the pattern of the values are being respected or not?

**---EDIT---**

Here is my actual query;

[image]

Which is returning all the records, instead of excluding the 1st one.

**-- EDIT 2 : Following @Wolfgang Kluge response;**

but still in vain! :(

[image]
Many thanks

Comment: No way with LIKE wildcards to check for *The following characters should be numeric*  - there is no `+` quantifier. Is the number of these characters fixed?

Comment: No, the number of numeric can vary.. Only the leading character is an alphabet..

Comment: you may try `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `[a-z]` - it depends on the collation you set (you can try `SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' = 'a' THEN 'CASE INSENSITIVE' ELSE 'CASE SENSITIVE' END`, too)

Answer (score 1):

There's no (full) regex in SQL Server 2008, but there's pattern matching - though it lacks of quantifiers.

<s>Not tested yet(!), but maybe you could try something like:</s>
[Tested wit sqlfiddle now](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/140d8/1). Use:

```
WHERE x LIKE '[a-z][0-9]%'
  AND x NOT LIKE '[a-z][0-9]%[^0-9]%'
```

`[a-z][0-9]%`

- `[a-z]`
  match character `a` to `z` (I think SQL Server is case independent most of the time - if not, use `[a-zA-Z]`)
- `[0-9]`
  match character `0` to `9`
- `%`
  match any characters

So this tests the start conditions..

`[a-z][0-9]%[^0-9]%`

- `[a-z][0-9]%`
  same as above
- `[^0-9]`
  see if there's a character not in the range `0` to `9`

Comment: Thnx for the reply.. I already tried the 1st one `x LIKE '[a-z][0-9]%'` but in vain.

Comment: @Nadeem_MK There's only one version! You have to use both lines in conjunction...

Comment: Tested it but it does not work. nothing is being returned at all. But 1 question, Do i have to run add any function for the regEx to run?

Comment: Hmm.. That's on MySQL and my question concerns on MS SQL 2008

Comment: I thought I used SQL Server 2008 in sqlfiddle... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/140d8/1

Comment: Oups, that's true, working perfectly on SQLFiddle.. But still not working on my SQL Server. Do I have any configuration to alter that I may be missing out? Like `clr enabled` for example?

Comment: no, no config needed. If I look at your code above, I see some differences. Just start with the example from sqlfiddle and change it to your needs

Comment: but it does not work, please see edit in my question where I added another screenshot of my actual query, including your response

Comment: Did you see the comment to your example?

Comment: Did try it, but to no avail. :(

Comment: Then create a fiddle with your table/data